# How to know if the android device supports multi users?

Tags: android, android-multiple-users

Android 4.2 supports multiple user spaces "on shareable devices such as tablets"(http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers). How do I know if a specific device is a "shareable device"?

Can I programmatically check if the device supports multiple users?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unfortunately, at least in any reliable fashion. API Level 17 means the OS is capable of multiple user spaces, but whether or not there's a Settings option for it will vary. I think the plan is for tablet-sized things to have multiple users, and phone-sized things not, but that might wind up being the choice of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hidden API at UserManager.supportsMultipleUsers(). You can access this using the following method which uses reflection, though this technique is not normally recommended because the API could change in a later release.

```
public static boolean supportsMultipleUsers() {
  try {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
     // return UserManager.supportsMultipleUsers();
     return (Boolean(UserManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("supportsMultipleUsers").invoke(null));
  }
  catch (Exception e) {}
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is enough for you to check if multiple users accounts have been created on the device, you can use `UserManager.getUserCount()` (after ensuring the SDK version is > 16).

I don't know if it's possible to distinguish if multiple users are theoretically possible, but only one has been used so far from no multi-user support at all.

**EDIT:** This solution does actually not work, it seems it requires a system-level permission. See here for details [UserManager getUserCount() (Jelly Bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13508258/1966616)

Comment: That's good, but it's not exactly what I wanted. But I assume then that there is no way to know if it's _possible_ to have multiple accounts.

Comment: Does it require any permission? According to this link: stackoverflow.com/q/13508258/878126 , it seems impossible to do it, as it's a system permission. Is it possible using root, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I actually never tried, but it seems that way based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13508258/1966616

Answer (score -2):

You can check the Android version with the following code:

```
int oSversion = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

if (osVersion > 16) {
   // This phone supports multi-user   
}
```

Comment: That does not work. A Nexus 10 allows multiple user spaces, while a Galaxy Nexus does not, each running Android 4.2 and having an `SDK_INT` (note: not `SDK`) of 17.

Comment: Well, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17 really says "100% it doesn't".