# Android UserManager: How to use the setRestriction method?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an app which can impose certain restrictions on the user (such as blacklisting certain apps or making a restricted profile which operates in kiosk mode). The new UserManager API's seem to have methods to do that.
However, I'm not sure how "setUserRestrictions()"  can be used to apply such restrictions. The sample app does not have any examples for the same.

Could someone point me to a sample app/code snippet which demonstrates the use of the setUserRestriction methods? Also, what sort of restrictions can we apply using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserManager.setUserRestrictions() throws:
java.lang.SecurityException: You need MANAGE_USERS permission to: setUserRestrictions

According to [UserManager getUserCount() (Jelly Bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508258/usermanager-getusercount-jelly-bean) it is not possible in an app.