# MANAGE_USERS permission not found in `android.permission` list

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I want to use [UserManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html) in my code. But for that it requires the permission `MANAGE_USERS`

I tried adding it in the manifest but there is no permission listing in manifest called `MANAGE_USERS`.

Then I tried adding this line

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />`

but still it gives error while running , says

`java.lang.SecurityException: You need MANAGE_USERS permission to: query user`

My minSdk version is 14. How can I add this permission? Thanks in advance..

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508258/usermanager-getusercount-jelly-bean

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your app with platform signature to use this permission. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651653/5925259) maybe helpful for you.

Comment: I also face this problem but no answer help me. Please help me.

Comment: @user11469878 please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature/3651653#3651653

Comment: thanks for reply. This is problem is occur after publishing app to playstore and in users device. In my device its work well.

Answer (score 0):

You have add below permission to query the user

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
```

But application should be System or Signed app.